# nvd3 donut chart is not showing all lables

Tags: angularjs, nvd3.js, donut-chart

[Donutchart Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OP9Oz.png)

I'm drawing the chat as shown in image, but the percentage label is not showing for all slices in the donut chart. only 12 labels are showing. I want to show percentage for all the labels that are shown in legend with out over lapping.can some one help.

here's my code:

js:

```
    nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart = nv.models.pieChart()
        .x(function(d) { return d.value })
        .y(function(d) { return d.count })
        .showLabels(true)     //Display pie labels
       // .labelThreshold(0.1)  //Configure the minimum slice size for labels to show up
        .labelType("percent") //Configure what type of data to show in the label. Can be "key", "value" or "percent"
        .donut(true)          //Turn on Donut mode. Makes pie chart look tasty!
        .donutRatio(0.35)     //Configure how big you want the donut hole size to be.
        .valueFormat(d3.format(',.0d'));
    ;

    d3.select("#chart svg")
        .datum(data)  
        .transition().duration(350)
        .call(chart);

    return chart;
});
var data=[{
      "field":"toyota_series",
      "value":"Prius",
      "count":95903},
    {
      "field":"toyota_series",
      "value":"Camry",
      "count":54512},
    {
      "field":"toyota_series",
      "value":"Mirai",
      "count":45261},
    {
      "field":"toyota_series",
      "value":"Tacoma",
      "count":26961},
    {
      "field":"toyota_series",
      "value":"Corolla",
      "count":22355},
    {
      "field":"toyota_series",
      "value":"RAV4",
      "count":21737},
    {
      "field":"toyota_series",
      "value":"Avalon",
      "count":10759},
    {
      "field":"toyota_series",
      "value":"Sienna",
      "count":9820},
    {
      "field":"toyota_series",
      "value":"Tundra",
      "count":9224},
    {
      "field":"toyota_series",
      "value":"4Runner",
      "count":8542},
    {
      "field":"toyota_series",
      "value":"Highlander",
      "count":7686},
    {
      "field":"toyota_series",
      "value":"Land Cruiser",
      "count":7381},
    {
      "field":"toyota_series",
      "value":"Yaris",
      "count":4217},
    {
      "field":"toyota_series",
      "value":"Matrix",
      "count":4072},
    {
      "field":"toyota_series",
      "value":"Prius c",
      "count":1960},
    {
      "field":"toyota_series",
      "value":"Sequoia",
      "count":1924},
    {
      "field":"toyota_series",
      "value":"Prius v",
      "count":1281},
    {
      "field":"toyota_series",
      "value":"FJ Cruiser",
      "count":947},
    {
      "field":"toyota_series",
      "value":"Venza",
      "count":841},
    {
      "field":"toyota_series",
      "value":"FT-1",
      "count":178},
    {
      "field":"toyota_series",
      "value":"PM",
      "count":16},
    {
      "field":"toyota_series",
      "value":"Prius-Plug-in-Hybrid",
      "count":1}]
```

html:

```
<div id="chart">
            <svg></svg>
        </div>
```

css:

```
#chart{
height:485px;
```

}

Comment: Have you tried `chart.labelsOutside(true)` ?

Comment: this is working but not showing labels for all slices in chart. out of 21 slices it is showing only 12 labels. And I want to do something like an arrow or line that denotes slice to percentage out side chart.